# Is there any ternary operator for just single if condition in dart?

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart, conditional-statements

In dart we have plenty of ternary operators.
But do we have one ternary operator just for if condition?

Example

In condition

```
if (num == 1){
  print(true);
} else {
  print(false);
}
```

In ternary

```
print(num == 1 ? true : false);
```

So do we have any ternary operator just for true condition like above example?

```
if (num == 1) {
   print(true);
}
```

Comment: For what purpose you asking ? to build a widget ?

Comment: No,
I just want to use it in `dart` only.

Comment: If you can say the real purpose we can suggest any logic for that !

Comment: Actually there is no problem at all, i just wanted a very clean code and that's why i raised this question.
Anyways thank you guys : )

Comment: print(num == 1 ??: true );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The conditional operator `?`/`:` in Dart requires all three operands.
It does so because all expressions must have a value, and if you could do just `e1 ? e2`, then the expression has *no* value if `e1` is false.

It's not impossible to conceive of a binary conditional operator where the missing expression defaults to `null`, say `(e1?:elseExpression)` or `(e1?thenExpression:)`, but then you can also just write the `null`, and saving four letters is probably not worth the potential loss of readability.

Ob-nitpick. The conditional operator in Dart is one of two ternary operators (operators requiring three operands, like binary operators require two operands), the other ternary operator being `[]=`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, since && is short-circuiting, we can use:

b && f(args) to replace if(b){ f(args);}

Where if b is true, function f will be executed. The drawback is that f must return a bool.  A true() wrapper function could be used.